# Reading lines from curses window into separate strings

Tags: c, arrays, pdcurses

I'm trying to read a file which has some encrypted content...the encryption is that every character except '\n' and "-" has had 4 subtracted from it and then xor-ed with 150....after reading the encrypted characters from the file, i put them in a string and do some processing(editing) with curses library.Then i encrypt the string again and put them back in the file.But the encryption isnt working.

I put all the contents of the decrypted file into a string.then broke the string into parts based on the \n characters and stored them into separate line arrays(2d) which represent consecutive lines in the curses window.Then tried to implement some cursor control to edit the lines and store the newly edited lines into the line arrays(2d).then i put them back into a temp file.After that,i tried to encrypt the characters and finally put them into original file.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<curses.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
if((fp1=fopen("demo.txt","rb"))==NULL)
{
    printf("\n\n\t\t\t\t     Could not open file! Press any key to return\n");
    _getch();
    return;
}
fclose(fp1);
int xrow,xcol,row,col,i=0,j,k=0,L=0,ch1,x;
char a[1405],ab[100][1405],c;
fp1=fopen("demo.txt" , "rb")
while(1)
{
    c=fgetc(fp1);
    a[i]=c;
    i++;
    if(feof(fp1))
        break;
}
fclose(fp1);
a[i]='\0';
i=0;
initscr();
getmaxyx(stdscr,xrow,xcol);
for(j=0;j<=strlen(a);j++,k++)
{
    if(a[j]=='\n')
    {
        ab[i][k]='\0';
        k=-1;
        i++;
        continue;
    }
    ab[i][k]=a[j];
}
cbreak();
keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
{
    mvaddnstr(k,0,ab[k],-1);
    refresh();
}
echo();
l=0;
while(1)
{
    noecho();
    ch1=getch();
    getyx(stdscr,row,col);
    switch(ch1)
    {
    case KEY_LEFT:
        refresh();
        if((col-1)<0)
        {
            beep();
        }
        else
        {
            col--;
        }
        wmove(stdscr,row,col);
        refresh();
        break;

    case KEY_RIGHT:
        if((col+1)>119)
        {
            beep();
        }
        else
        {
            col++;
        }
        wmove(stdscr,row,col);
        refresh();
        break;

    case KEY_UP:
        if((row-1)<0)
        {
            beep();
        }
        else
        {
            row--;
        }
        wmove(stdscr,row,col);
        refresh();
        break;

    case KEY_DOWN:
        if((row+1)>29)
        {
            beep();
        }
        else
        {
            row++;
        }
        wmove(stdscr,row,col);
        refresh();
        break;

    case 8:
        delch();
        refresh();
        break;


    case 10:
        for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
        {
            x=strlen(ab[k]);
            mvinnstr(k,0,ab[k],x);
        }
        L=1;
        break;

    default:
        addch(ch1);
        refresh();
        break;
    }
    if(l!=0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
clear();
refresh();
endwin();
system("cls");
for(k=0;k<=i;k++)
{
    printf("%s\n",ab[k]);
}
getch();
k=0;
L=0;
if((fp1=fopen("demo.txt","wb+"))!=NULL)
{
    while(1)
    {
        if(k>i)
        {
            break;
        }
        if(ab[k][l]=='\0')
        {
            c='\n';
            l=0;
            k++;
            fputc(c,fp1);
        }
        else
        {
            c=ab[k][l];
            l++;
            fputc(c,fp1);
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp1);
}
```

when printing the line arrays on the curses window,i get weird output.... any help would be greatly appreciated!this is a part of my project  and I'm actually trying to implement a pseudo text-editor like function >.<

Edit: It looks like the problem is arising after the while loop containing the switch statement is executed.The for loop printing the line arrays print weird characters after that. Also removed the whole encrypt-decrypt work.

Comment: There's no reason to mix decryption and curses in this question. Make separate programs, one with decryption and normal output, and one with curses but no decryption, and see which of them has the problem. Then ask just about that one.

Comment: I removed the encryption but the problem still persists.So there it is :(

Comment: As posted, the program doesn't compile. With that fixed, I can't reproduce the problem.